# Is there software to manually OCR / teach OCR for handwriting (non-english) texts?

Tags: pdf, software-rec, ocr, tesseract

I had a problem that can't solve Tesseract/Abbyy Finereader etc - they can't recognize handwriting Russian as example.
So I search

1. OCR software for such things
2. or a way to manually OCR my pdfs (create layers, draw squares, fill it with text by hands)
3. maybe teach OCR engine locally for automation after some manually job